# how do I tag a production release automatically in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins, gradle, build, tags

How do I tag a production release in Jenkins automatically? I am using gradle for build.

- I would like to tag a production release only when the build is
  successful.
- I would like to use a custom name for the tag (like
  PR_[App Name]_[Time stamp of release])
- I would want the tag stored in
  svn (in [project location]/tags) location

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try this Plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin

[image: Example config]

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and will let you know.